# Usage of the word 'as' meaning 'considering'

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> Will they accept his invitation, unsociable **as** they are?

Does the last clause mean, "considering how unsociable they are?"

Comment: No. *As* does **not** mean "considering" here. At best it could be a case of "being" elided. Read it as "Will they accept his invitation, ** (they) being as** unsociable as they are?" In which case, *as* has the usual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

[As:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as_1)

> You use as when you are indicating what someone or something is or is thought to be, or what function they have.

(Collins Dictionary)

so, “unsociable as they are”  expresses the idea that you or people  think they are unsociable.

Answer (score -2):

This is a special ***concessive*** use of 'as'.  The Cambridge English Dictionary cites:-

> **as** (conjunction) ALTHOUGH

It gives the following example, parallel to your cited use:-

> Angry as he was, he couldn't help smiling.